# pmatch returning character match in wrong way

Tags: r, character, matching, map-matching

I have a character word matrix (3 by 3) and a dictionary (n by 1). I want to find the characters match with the dictionary, will be replaced by the character position exists in the dictionary and all the unmatched words will be removed (either NA, or NULL). I have tried simple `pmatch`, but it is not working. I am looking for the result like this,

```
1    5    2
1    4    NA
3    NA   2
```

but getting result in this way, `[1]  1 NA  3  5  4 NA  2 NA NA`

I tried the code bellow,

```
a <- matrix(c("456_rr", "432_uu", "522_kk", "456_rr", "432_tt", "522", "456_ss", "432", "522_kk"), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) # WordTable

b <- matrix(c("456_rr","522_kk","456_ss", "432_tt", "432_uu"), nrow = 5, ncol = 1) # Dictionary

c <- pmatch(a, b)

print(c)
```

Comment: ufs, thanks @akrun . but still far from expected result. And how to keep it matrix wise?

Comment: I just updated with a solution.  You can convert it to matrix either by calling `matrix` or use the `dim`.  Are you sure that the values in the expected are correct?

Comment: Let me know if that is a typo.  Or else I will delete my answer

Comment: That was a typo, your answer is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nrow` in the 'b' is not correct.  It should be `5`

```
b <- matrix(c("456_rr","522_kk","456_ss", "432_tt", 
     "432_uu"), nrow = 5, ncol = 1) 
v1 <- pmatch(a,b)
m1 
#[1]  1 NA  3  5  4 NA  2 NA NA

dim(m1) <- dim(a)
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    5    2
#[2,]   NA    4   NA
#[3,]    3   NA   NA
```

If we need to get the index of duplicates, use `duplicates.ok=TRUE` which is by default FALSE

```
`dim<-`(pmatch(a, b, duplicates.ok=TRUE), dim(a))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    5    2
#[2,]    1    4    2
#[3,]    3   NA    2
```

Comment: thanks @akrun for this big help, but still it is not the expected positions from the dictionary. Is it the limitation of `pmatch`?

Comment: @Noah changed the output.  We need to add `duplicates.ok`